# react-native on android crash when requesting camera permissions

Tags: android, react-native, permissions

my phone (android 8.1.0)  keeps crashing when i request the permission to use the camera in react native.  I use `android:targetSdkVersion="25"` in my Android Manifest.

```
componentDidMount(){
(async () => {
    await this.requestCameraPermission();
})();}




  async requestCameraPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                   'so you can take awesome pictures.'
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the camera")
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the crash text to the question? That is, use logcat to see it and paste it here.

Comment: Have u imported `PermissionsAndroid ` ?

Comment: i added android PermissionsAndroid